# Copying the Cells Below A Text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy 3 entire rows below a cell which includes a text.

I've already wrote this but there are some issues that I can't solve due to being a beginner of VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SearchandInsertRows()

Dim lRow As Long,  iRow As Long

With Worksheets("Main_Page")
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlup).Row
    For iRow = lRow to 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(iRow, "A").Value = Range("D5") Then
            .Rows(iRow).Resize(3).Insert
        End if
    Next iRow
End With

End Sub
```

I want excel to read the entire A column and find the cell which has same text with cell `D5` (Text is BillNumber). Then add 3 blank rows above that. Lastly copy the three cells below BillNumber and paste it to recently created 3 blank rows.

Here is screenshot to make it more understandable.

[image]

Comment: What "issues" are you having specifically? If D5 is on another sheet you should add a sheet reference.

Comment: No, there is no problem with adding blank rows. The problem is I don't exactly know how to copy the 3 rows below "BillNumber" and paste it to the rows that I've created with this code.

Comment: Is D5 on a different sheet? If not, when you insert rows it will move.

Comment: No its in the same sheet but at the first row. The text is below that. So when i insert rows it does not move. There is no problem with that.

Comment: How is D5 at the first row? You should at least change the end value of your loop.

Comment: According to the image, you are looking for the D6-value in cells of column A. When found, you want to insert the row of the found cell and two rows below, above the found cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, remove the MsgBox lines, they are for debugging.

```
Sub insertPaste()
    Dim D5Val As String, wk As Workbook, fVal As Range
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    With wk.Sheets("Sheet1")
        'Value from D5
        D5Val = .Range("D5").Value
        'Find D5 on column A
        Set fVal = .Columns("A:A").Find(D5Val, , xlValues, , xlNext)
        If fVal Is Nothing Then
            'Not found
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        Else
            'Found
            MsgBox "Found at: " & fVal.Address
            'Insert 3 Cells on top of the cell found with the data from the 3 cells below
            .Range("A" & (fVal.Row + 1) & ":A" & (fVal.Row + 3)).Copy
            .Range("A" & fVal.Row & ":A" & (fVal.Row + 2)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is still an issue. I guess i couldn't explain my problem clear enough, sorry that is my bad. When i insert 3 rows above the cell in A column(which has same content with D5), i want excel to copy the 3 rows below that moved cell, not 3 rows below D5. So anytime i insert 3 more rows, it still has to copy the 3 rows below that cell and paste it above to the recently created 3 rows.

Comment: @AlphaCenta - It might be helpful to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54011705/edit) and post some screen caps of initial data and expected results. Upload the images to imgur.com and someone with enough reputation will be able to insert them for you

Comment: FInd is a good way to go, but you might need to allow for more than one instance.

Comment: It has been corrected, it is still taking the value from D5, looking on Column A for the value, finding it, copying the 3 cells Below the found value and inserting 3 cells above with the copied cells.

Comment: @SJR, true but since it was never mentioned that the value would repeat, I went with it.

Comment: Ricardo - fair enough. The screenshot is not what I was envisaging - why don't you just shift column A down @AlphaCenta?

Comment: @Ricardo - The percentage values come from another sheet. Every month bill number changes like 19,20,21. I need to shift the last months bill(let's say it's 21). It already gets percentages from another sheet and billnumber from D6. So 21 needs to be shifted 3 rows below and those rows which starts with 21 needs to be copied to the recently created blank rows. Then i will change the billnumber in D6 to 22 and current month's values will be changed just after i change them in other sheet.

Comment: @AlphaCenta with the screenshots it now makes more sense and my code would just have to be modified very little to make it work. I wont be able to edit the answer until later tonight, but I want to point out that all you need is there. My code shows you a way to find the billnumber in column A, it shows you how to insert 3 cells on top of the cell that it found, you can add a line so it adds 3 more on column B as well. It copies the 3 cells from column A but can also be changed to copy the ones from column B. I encourage you to play with the code on the meantime, it's the best way to learn.

Comment: @Ricardo A - Thank you so much. I've just changed a few numbers in your code and it works smoothly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

## Copy Cells Below Text Above Text

### The Code

```
Private Sub SearchandInsertRows()

    Dim lRow As Long, iRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Main_Page")
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For iRow = lRow To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(iRow, "A").Value = .Range("D6") Then
                .Rows(iRow).Resize(3).Insert
                .Rows(iRow + 3 & ":" & iRow + 5).Copy .Rows(iRow)
            End If
        Next iRow
    End With

End Sub
```